# Why doesn't ref.current.focus() work when running tests via the @testing-library/react-native libary?

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library

I'm attempting to write some tests for my react native app. A component in my app focuses a TextInput after a parent Pressable receives a press. I'm using a ref to identify and focus the TextInput element.

My desired functionality works just fine when running my app through expo, but my test is failing because it seems that the onFocus event is not being called.

Why isn't `ref.current.focus()` being called when running tests via the `@testing-library/react-native` library?

Here's my code:

## Foo.js

```
import {Pressable, TextInput} from "react-native";
import {useRef} from "react";

const Foo = (props) => {
    const inputRef = useRef()

    return (
        <Pressable testID={"pressable"} onPress={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>
            <TextInput ref={inputRef} testID={"input"} onFocus={props.onFocus} />
        </Pressable>
    )
}

export default Foo;
```

## Foo.test.js

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Foo from "./foo";

test('onFocus is called after press', () => {
    const mockFocus = jest.fn();
    render(<Foo onFocus={mockFocus} />)
    // fireEvent(screen.getByTestId("input"), 'focus');
    fireEvent.press(screen.getByTestId("pressable"));
    expect(mockFocus).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

This test fails with the following message:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an issue on the [RNTL GitHub page](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library) and received a [response](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/1069) from a contributor. Copying and pasting here for easy reference for anyone who might stumble upon this thread.

> This is expected as React Test Renderer which we use for rendering
> does not support `refs`. Check [#1006](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/1006) for more details.
>
> Since the behaviour of `focus()` triggering `onFocus` event would probably
> involve roundtrip to native side (from JS side), then you actually
> cannot test such behaviour using RNTL as we do not run native code (see
> [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/faq/) for details).
>
> That leaves you with following options:
>
> 1. Call `fireEvent.focus` to manually trigger `onFocus` on relevant
>    `TextInput`. Recommended in case `focus` assertion would be a part of a
>    step in a bigger test.
> 2. Use `createNodeMock` to pass `ref` creating function to `render` method, More details [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#ideas). Recommended in case you
>    just want to assert pressing button triggers `onFocus`.